# Stubbing Task returning method in async unit test

Tags: c#, unit-testing, task-parallel-library, async-await

Let's say I have the following class and an interface it depends on:

```
public class MyController
{
    private IRepository _repository;
    public MyController(IRepository repository)
    {
        _repository = repository;
    }

    public async Task MethodUnderTest(int someId)
    {
        var o = await _repository.FindById(someId);
        // update o
        await _repository.Commit();
    }
}

public interface IRepository
{
    Task Commit();
}
```

When I unit test this method I can do the following (using xUnit and Rhino Mocks):

```
[Fact]
public async Task MyTest()
{
    IRepository repositoryStub = MockRepository.GenerateStub<IRepository>();

    MyController controller = new MyController(repositoryStub);

    await controller.MethodUnderTest(1);
}
```

This fails with a *System.NullReferenceException : Object reference not set to an instance of an object*.

With the following StackTrace:

```
UnitTest.MyController.<MethodUnderTest>d__0.MoveNext() in 
\UnitTest\Class1.cs:line 35
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at \UnitTest\Class1.cs:line 20
```

Is it correct that this error occurs because the `Commit()` returns `null` and the statemachine generated for the async/await calls `MoveNext()` on a `null`?

I can fix this by doing something like:

```
repositoryStub.Expect(r => r.Commit()).Return(Task.FromResult<bool>(true);
```

But this feels a little strange.. I can use any `T` for `FromResult<T>` and the test will run. I can't find a `FromResult` method that will return a non-generic `Task`.

Does it matter what I use for `T`? Or should I fix this some other way?

Comment: It doesn't matter what type `T` you use since `Task<T>` extends `Task`. You could use `Task.Delay(0)` instead. If you don't care about the task itself you could change `MethodUnderTest` to return `_repository.Commit()` directly instead of creating an async method.

Comment: Repository.Commit() uses Entity Frameworks 6 new async features to save changes to the database. I use this from an ASP.NET MVC application. What do you mean by returning _repository.Commit() directly?

Comment: I mean `MethodUnderTest` could be `return _repository.Commit();` if you remove the `async` modifier, so it will just return a null task in your tests if you haven't stubbed `_repository.Commit()`.

Comment: OK.. this example is then a little to small. I have multiple awaits inside the MethodUnderTest so I can't remove the async keyword just for the Commit()

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You will need to return something; `async Task` methods cannot ever return `null`.

The `T` doesn't matter. You could declare a `static readonly Task SuccessTask = Task.FromResult<object>(null);` as a helper constant if you want. I have [similar constants](http://nitoasyncex.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=TaskConstants) in my AsyncEx library.

Answer (score 7):

If you are targeting .NET Framework 4.6 or later, you can now use `.Returns(Task.CompletedTask)` instead which is slightly shorter.